# Angularjs 1.2.x Injector:modulerrr error even a after adding ngRoute

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am teaching myself angularjs and I can't seem to crack this error. I have tried trouble shooting. Given up, here is what I got.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Simple App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-view></div>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="_js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: "_templates/home.html",
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

app.controller('HomeController', function() {

});
```

**error**

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.23%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A170)
>   angular.js:36(anonymous function) angular.js:36(anonymous function)
>   angular.js:3906r angular.js:325e angular.js:3872gc angular.js:3812c
>   angular.js:1444fc angular.js:1459Xc angular.js:1368(anonymous
>   function) angular.js:21949a angular.js:2573(anonymous function)
>   angular.js:2853r angular.js:325c angular.js:2852

http://jsfiddle.net/r91ymsu3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `ng-route` module script also for routing

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: don't be ashamed to ask something you might not know. the more we learn, the more we have uncertainties.